# Creating new column with letters v from beginning to last row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I add a new empty column with the letters 'v' from beginning to the last row.

df1:

```
    AM     
0   MA      
1   Ming    
2   Mo
```

Desired output for df1:

```
    AM    C     
0   MA    v    
1   Ming  v    
2   Mo    v
```

I get error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Sample'

When  I try this:

```
df1["C"] = np.nan
df1
df1["C"] = df1.Sample.str['v']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
df1['C'] = 'V'
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of df1 after executing this statement? It works perfectly fine for me. Which version of pandas and python are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

dd = pd.DataFrame(d)

print dd

one

a    1

b    2

c    3

dd = pd.DataFrame(d)

dd['df'] = 'test'

print dd

one    df

a    1  test

b    2  test

c    3  test